# How to give priority to spring bean with same id?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit4

In our project we are using spring with `Junit` for Junit testing. We have used `@ContextConfiguration` annotation for loading multiple file. We have two classes `AbstractContextJUnitTest` and `ContextJUnitTest` and `ContextJUnitTest` extends `AbstractContextJUnitTest`.

***During code flow I have noticed that same bean Id in multiple files with different bean types***. When I am testing these Junits and getting the below error.

**Error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean
>   named 'voterId' is expected to be of type [com.spring.test2.Student]
>   but was actually of type [com.spring.test2.Parent]

My requirement is Student bean should load with VoterId instead of Parent Bean.

Below are the java files and spring bean xml files:

**test.xml:**

```
<beans> 
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="voterId" class="com.spring.test2.Parent">
    <property name="Name" value="hai"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="system" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="transactionManager"

        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**test1.xml**

```
<beans>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="voterId" class="com.spring.test2.Student">
        <property name="name" value="hello"/>
        <property name="number" value="2080"/>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

**AbstractContextJUnitTest.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:/com/spring/test2/test1.xml")
public class AbstractContextJUnitTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{


}
```

**ContextJUnitTest.java**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/com/spring/test2/test.xml"})
public class ContextJUnitTest extends AbstractContextJUnitTest{


    @Test
    public void testStudent(){
        Student stud=applicationContext.getBean("voterId",Student.class);
        assertEquals(stud.getNumber(), 2080);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)?

```
<bean id="voterId" class="com.spring.test2.Student" primary="true">
        <property name="name" value="hello"/>
        <property name="number" value="2080"/>
</bean>
```

You have to use [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) for `com.spring.test2.Parent` wherever you need.

Or you can get the bean with type as:

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Student.class).get("voterI‌​d")
```

Comment: @sidharthapani   try this - `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Student.class).get("voterId")`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have extended classes in that order..and your test.xml doesn't have any bean with of Student. So it is simply following inheritance and found parent.
Below lines make it look for bean voterid in test.xml first and it found it there.
ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/com/spring/test2/test.xml"}) public class ContextJUnitTest

Comment: Can i override the locations attribute in Junit class. I mean using any method?

Comment: why would you do that...just exchange the parent and student beans in respective xml's...it should work fine.

Comment: What I posted is sample example for my project. But in my project I should not change this.